# How do I write/export a few matrices to an XLS file?

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, export

I have a lot of matrix variables. Some have more than 200 rows. How can I export them to an XLS or DAT file with their names? I tried the following:

```
d = {'X', 'Y'; X Y};
xlswrite('tempdata1.xls', d, 'Sheet1', 'A1');
```

What I got in the XLS file was only the strings 'X' and 'Y' but without the values of `X` and `Y`. `X` and `Y` should be vectors (7x1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `X` and `Y` are column vectors, try this:

```
xlswrite('tempdata1.xls', {'X' 'Y'}, 'Sheet1', 'A1');  %# Write the names
xlswrite('tempdata1.xls', [X Y], 'Sheet1', 'A2');      %# Write the data
```

The reason your cell array `d` didn't work is because [XLSWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html) requires all the cells in the cell array to have just one value in them. In your case, `X` and `Y` were *vectors*, not scalar numerical values or strings, as is the case in [this documentation example](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html#f15-479153).